# Let $\{v_1,..,v_m\}$ and $\{w_1,..,w_n\}$ be linearly independent sets such that $w_j \notin$ span($v_1,..,v_m$), is $v_1,..,v_m,w_1,..,w_n$ lin.ind?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-independence

Specifically, suppose that $v_1,...,v_m$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in some vector space $V$. Further, suppose that $w_1,...,w_n \in V$ is also linearly independent such that $w_j \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$ for all j. Does it follow that $v_1,...,v_m,w_1,...,w_n$ is linearly independent?

Comment: What are your thoughts? [Here are some guidelines on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 4):

It need not to be true. Consider $v=(1,2)$, $w_{1}=(1,0)$ and $w_{2}=(0,1)$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Appreciate the counter-example. As a follow-up, what condition (say as 'weak' as possible) would I need to also assume in order for my question to hold, that $v_1,...,v_m,w_1,...,w_n$ ends up linearly independent.